# How to convert content type application octet stream to csv in logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am using **http api** call for downloading D365 export csv file.
It is downloading in binary format "$content-type": "application/octet-stream"

```
 {
  "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "$content": "UEsDBBQAAAAIAL07VFMaQk8xFQcAAEkXAAAZAAAAQVZBVmV"
}
```

I tried the below code still it is not decoded properly and giving junk values. Please let me know  the correct way to get csv file.

*I think $content holds full file data not just the content.*

```
json(base64ToString(replace(body('Get_blob_content')?['$content'],'77u/','')))
@string(body('Download_the_package_file')['$content'])
```

[image]

Comment: when I used `string(triggerBody())` with `compose` connector it was working for me and could able to retrieve the csv file. Instead of using only content try sending the whole binary format.

Comment: thanks for you input, but still I am getting junk values... May be I am thinking  the problem is in Api call URI? from 2 days blocked here only

Comment: Can you please make sure if the data is extracted right? Also, I observe that you are exporting a CSV file but reading a .json file?

Comment: You are downloading a ZIP file, not CSV. AVAVendorMasterEntity.csv is inside the package.

Comment: yes it was ZIP file... I need to save as .zip and extract to get .csv file.. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observe that you are exporting a CSV file but reading a .json file from the blob.
Based on your provided information, we have 3 scenarios in place.

**1. If test.json file contains AVAVendorEntity.csv elements**
You can retrieve these files without the junk by using string expressions for the whole output.

***Example :***
if body contains

```
{
"$content-type":  "application/octet-stream",
"$content":  "Ww0KICB7DQogICAgImlkIjogIjEiLA0KICAgICJyZWNlaXZlciI6ICIgMTIzODUiLA0KICAgICJwYXlsb2FkIjogIiB7J21lc3NhZ2UnOiAndGVzdCAxJyIsDQogICAgIm9wZXJhdG9yIjogIiAnRW5naW5lSWQnOiAzIiwNCiAgICAic2VuZGVyIjogIiAnUGVyc29uSWQnOiAxIg0KICB9LA0KICB7DQogICAgImlkIjogIjIiLA0KICAgICJyZWNlaXZlciI6ICIgMTIzNDciLA0KICAgICJwYXlsb2FkIjogIiB7J21lc3NhZ2UnOiAndGVzdCAyJyIsDQogICAgIm9wZXJhdG9yIjogIiAnRW5naW5lSWQnOiAzIiwNCiAgICAic2VuZGVyIjogIiAnUGVyc29uSWQnOiAyIg0KICB9DQpd"
}
```

then we use

```
string(triggerBody())
```

[image]

**2. If there are only CSV elements but having .json extension**
If this is the case then we use JSON instead of string

***Example:***
If body contains

```
{
"$content-type":  "application/octet-stream",
"$content":  "dXJsCXVzZXJfaWQJdG9rZW5faWQJdXNlcm5hbWUJcGFzc3dvcmQNCmh0dHA6Ly93d3cudHdpdHRlci5jb20vYTg1CTEJMTIzMTIzMTIzCWFiaGluYXYJYWJjDQpodHRwOi8vd3d3LnR3aXR0ZXIuY29tL3NvYnRpYW5raXQJMgk4OTk4OTkJYW5raXQJZGVmDQpodHRwOi8vd3d3LnR3aXR0ZXIuY29tL2FiaGlqaXRrYW5lCTMJNDU2MTIzMTIzCWFiaGlqaXQJeHl6DQo="
}
```

then we use

```
json(triggerBody())
```

[image]

**3. Change the content-type accordingly**

**4. The problem might be in API call while extracting the data**

For converting the desired output into .csv one of the workarounds is you can always store them into blob using the .csv extension and then it will automatically convert the data into CSV format.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the source file was zip file content so I was getting junk after conversion.

Comment: I am having same issue only my response will have a pdf file which i can see in postman how can i save the pdf file any ideas.